# How mult and mfhi are implemented in vhdl?

Tags: assembly, vhdl, mips, multiplication

I am having trouble with implementing those two operations in vhdl. I don't even have an idea. Is mult ok like this?

```
signal a: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0):= x"0000";

a<= "00" & a(15 downto 2);
q<="00" & q(15 downto 2);
a<=b + a;
a<='0' & a(15 downto 1);
q<='0' & q(15 downto 1);
a<=b + a;
a<='0' & a(15 downto 1);
q<='0' & q(15 downto 1);
```

That's how I did it, but when it comes to mhfi i don't have any ideas.

Comment: You seem to be treating VHDL like a SW language. It is not. It is a HARDWARE Description Language. You need to think what hardware you are expecting before you start to write any VHDL. For example, what hardware would you expect to be produced by `a<=a(15 downto 2);`? This won't run, because `a` is 16 bits and `a(15 downto 2)` is 14 bits. Secondly, you need to find out about VHDL signals. You cannot assign to a signal on one line and then expect it's value to be updated on a following line, because a VHDL _signal_ represents a connection...

Comment: ...and the expression to the right of the _assignment operator_ represents the value that is _being driven_ on to that connection. Basically, VHDL signals DO NOT behave like variables in a SW language.

Comment: How should i do it then? Could you hust give me some advice to on how to start?

Comment: So i need to declare multiple signals and the the final one connect to my result signal?

Comment: Here's how to do multiplication in VHDL: use the `*` operator. If you synthesise that, you'll get lot's of combinational logic. If that's what you want then problem solved. If it's not, then you need to think what hardware you want and write the VHDL that implements that hardware. That would be a hardware design task. Once you've done that, you need to know enough VHDL to implement that logic. It seems like you're trying to run before you can walk here. It seems like to need to find out about how to design multipliers and then how to implement hardware in VHDL before you can go any further.